# I am trying to build a contact form in Vue.js and Php but i am getting errors i am not quite sure how to solve this problem

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I am trying to build a contact form in vue js and PHP but its not working and i am getting erros i used internet sources to build this form watched many tutorials i am not sure how to solve this. And i am very new to vuejs any kind of help would be appreciated

here's my code

```
<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
    errorMessage: "",
    successMessage: "",
    errors: [],
    trx_no: "",
    name: "",
    country: "",
    email: "",
    mobile_no: "",
    myAddress: "",
    newUser: {trx_no: "", name: "", country: "", email: "", mobile: ""}
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.getAllUsers();
  },

  myAddress: function() {
    return this.$store.state.myAddress;
  },

  methods: {
    saveUser: function(){
      //console.log(this.newUser);
      var formData = this.toFormData(this.newUser);

      axios.post('http://localhost:8888/vue-and-php/public/api/update-info-form.php?action=update', formData, { crossdomain: true })
      .then((response) => {

        this.newUser = {trx_no: "", name: "", country: "", email: "", mobile: ""};

        if(response.data.error){
          this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
        }else{
          this.getAllUsers();
        }
        });
    },
    toFormData: function(obj){
      var form_data = new FormData();
      for(var key in obj){
        form_data.append(key, obj[key]);
      }
      return form_data;
    },
    clearMessage: function(){
      this.errorMessage = "";
      this.successMessage = "";
    },
    //validation
    checkForm: function (e) {
      this.errors = [];

      //if (!this.trx_no) {
      //  this.errors.push("TRX Address Required.");
      //}

      if (!this.name) {
        this.errors.push("Name Required.");
      }
      if (!this.country) {
        this.errors.push("Country Required.");
      }
      if (!this.email) {
        this.errors.push('Email Required.');
      } else if (!this.validEmail(this.email)) {
        this.errors.push('Valid Email Address Required.');
      }
      if (!this.mobile_no) {
        this.errors.push("Phone Number Required.");
      }

      if (!this.errors.length) {
        return true;
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    },

    validEmail: function (email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is the contact form

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <div class="update-info">
      <div class="feature-text myinv-title">
        <h5 class="title title-sm">Update your information</h5>
      </div>
      <form
        id="app"
        @submit="checkForm"
        method="post"
        novalidate="true"
        >

    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please fill in all the fields</b>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="error in errors" class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
    </p>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="trx">TRX Address No.</label>
        <input
          id="trx"
          class="form-control trx-address-nooverflow"
          v-model="myAddress"
          type="text"
          name="TRX Address"
          readonly
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          class="form-control"
          v-model="name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Country</label>
        <country-select
         id="Country"
         class="form-control"
         v-model="country"
         :country="country"
         topCountry="US" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="email">Email ID</label>
        <input
          id="email"
          class="form-control"
          v-model="email"
          type="email"
          name="email"
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="email">Mobile No</label>
        <input
          id="mobile"
          class="form-control"
          v-model="mobile_no"
          type="text"
          name="mobile"
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <div class="top-30">
          <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-btn btn-grad btn-submit" @click="saveUser();"/>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance and #respect

NOTE: API is working fine I've tested it in Postman

Comment: It will be helpful if you can also post the error message.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your precious this is what I am getting [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getAllUsers is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what errors you get, but I see a problem with how the form is submitted.

Some changes I recommend:

The form:
`<form id="app" @submit="saveUser" method="post" novalidate="true"> ... </form>`

The button:
`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-btn btn-grad btn-submit" />`

The `saveUser` method:

```
saveUser(event){
  event.preventDefault()

  this.checkForm()

  if(!this.errors.length) {
     var formData = this.toFormData(this.newUser);

      axios.post('http...')
      // rest of the code
  }
}
```

Can't test it as I don't have the project, but this should help.

---

However, instead of the above approach, I would recommend to do the validation at input level and let each input component deal with its own validation logic and messages. The submit button to become enabled only when no errors exist in the form. There are many component libraries for this. For the user would be much better experience to see the errors in real time than with the above way to have a list of errors upon trying to submit the form.

Comment: thank you for the recommended changes and your time but I am also getting this erros -> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getAllUsers is not a function"

Comment: and then if i just click the form even after making changes you recommened i get this error -> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined" and i fill in all the fields then i click again this i get this error-> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined"

Comment: The errors you mention are saying that you don't have imported what the errors complains about. About the preventDefault error, I actually wrote the code from my head here in the browser, more as a direction and not exactly as copy paste ready.